# AIX 7.2 Gitlab runner core dumps on launch

Tags: gitlab, crash, aix, runner

I have an AIX 7.2 machine (oslevel=7200-03-02-1846) that I want to connect to Gitlab.
Attempting to use the gitlab runner published by PowerDevOps (Gitlab Runner 15.2.0) results in a coredump:

`bash-5.1# ./gitlab-runner install --user=runner --working-directory=/home/runner/gitlab_runner`

`Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

Has anyone had experience with this runner?
Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Exactly what program did you download from where?

Comment: The runner came from here: https://www.power-devops.com/gitlab

Comment: Execution stops on this statement: ` <runtime.check+476>:      lbarx   r31,0,r6` It seems to have been compiled for Power8, while your processor is earlier (`lsattr -El proc0 -a type`). You can try to compile it from source, but expect troubles with that too.